# Google Assistant "Add Milk to Shopping list"

Tags: android, google-voice, google-voice-actions

I am trying to use Google Voice Assistance in my application. I could see following functionality happen in Google Assistance in almost all the Android mobile.

Say for example I am saying "Add milk to shopping list" to Google Assistance and it is getting added in Google Assistance Shopping list like as below image

[image]

I could even see the shopping list when I tap on "View list" text in same Google assistance conversion page like below.

[image]

So, Here my question is **Can i Get "Add milk to Shopping list or App name" voice action in my application** ? If not, could anyone please let me know the best way to receive this kind of voice action in my application.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean if I say "Add milk to Shopping list" then action should be taken by your app ?

Comment: Yes. Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Action SDK for this. If you want something like action should open your app then go through this predefined actions https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/

If you want add custom commands this then one of the app does, you have decompile the code and understand https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.Commandr&hl=en